Make non overlapping property of interface/type optional
I want to "merge" multiple interfaces/types in Typescript. The outcoming interface should have all shared property mandatory and all "not-shared" propertys optional.
Here an example:
interface ShopUser {
   userId: string
   boughtItems: string[]
}

interface BlogUser {
   userId:string
   viewedBlogs: string[]
}

interface AppUser {
   userId: string
   appSessions: string[]
}


The Outcome should be something like this:
interface DBUser {
   userId: string          // mandatory, because all childs have this property
   boughtItems?:string[]   // optional now
   viewedBlogs?:string[]   // optional now
   appSessions?:string[]   // optional now
}

I already tried these things:
type DBUser = ShopUser | BlogUser | AppUser // now only userId is usable. The Rest is unknown

type DBUser = ShopUser & BlogUser & AppUser // now all Properties are mandatory...

Using something like Omit<ShopUser, "boughtItems"> and then retyping seems somehow not elegant to me and since our Interfaces are much more complex it also ends in a mess and is not very reusable.

What if they have the same key but different type?

https://tsplay.dev/mq2yJW

@mochaccino Regarding your first message: I havnt thought about it, but we would keep the types the same.

@mochaccino Regarding second Comment:
Wow, it works. I really dont understand what you did, but this looks like super high level Typescript. If you post it as an answere i ll mark it as the solution.

In a union A | B, the accessible keys are those that are shared between A and B. Therefore, keyof (A | B) gives us the shared keys. The type should be A[K] | B[K] or (A | B)[K].
For the keys that aren't shared, we can just take the intersection A & B and omit the shared keys to get the difference of the two types. Then we can add Partial to make all the properties optional.
The resulting type is too complex and TypeScript will display the uncomputed type. You can force TypeScript to "evaluate" it using a conditional type and a mapped type.
type Merge<A, B> = {
    [K in keyof (A | B)]: A[K] | B[K]; // shared keys
} & ( // intersect with
    Partial<Omit<A & B, keyof (A | B)>> // the difference
        extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never // pretty display
);

Merge all three types now:
type DBUser = Merge<Merge<ShopUser, BlogUser>, AppUser>;

Playground link

It is also possible to write a type Merge such that it takes a tuple of types and merges them in the same way:
type DBUser = Merge<[ShopUser, BlogUser, AppUser]>;

But that is something for the reader to figure out ;')

Wait, so what's wrong with type Merge<A, B> = Partial<A | B> & Pick<A & B, keyof (A | B)>? That seems to pass tests I managed to invent and is much easier to comprehend.

@STerliakov It doesn't seem like it produces the type OP was after but I believe it is functionally similar: https://tsplay.dev/W4gQ1m The only notable difference is that the output is a union so that it would be distributed in a conditional type. Also I wrote my solution with differently typed keys in mind. That type you have shown instead resolves all keys to never which is probably undesirable: https://tsplay.dev/NaAZBN OP never specified if they wanted to work with differently typed keys but I added it anyways for anyone else reading that may require such behaviour.

Oh, cool, I didn't even consider potentially different types for the same key,

This type is what you want, userId is mandatory while the other properties are optional
type DBUser = Partial<ShopUser | BlogUser | AppUser> & {
    [K in keyof (ShopUser | BlogUser | AppUser)]: (ShopUser & BlogUser & AppUser)[K]
};

or create a merge type like this
type Merge<A, B> = Partial<A | B> & {
    [K in keyof (A | B)]: (A & B)[K]
};

type DBUser = Merge<Merge<ShopUser, BlogUser>, AppUser>;

